# Trying to understand button behaviour

Tags: ios, swift

this is my first project, and i try to set a button title for some time and after it should reset.
This my code:

The first (test) snippet simply tries to set immediately to "tapped" and then after 2 secs to reset to "tap me".
What i see is disappering the button for 2sec and then only "tap me" again!?

```
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBAction func button1Tapped(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.setTitle("tapped", forState: .Highlighted)
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2.0)
    sender.setTitle("tap me", forState: .Normal)
}
```

The second example is more what i really want!
But for some reason I immediately fail here, because the alert simply does not show up!?

Any hints?

```
    @IBOutlet weak var button2: UIButton!
@IBAction func button2Tapped(sender: AnyObject) {
}

func isOK(sender:UIAlertAction!){
    button2.setTitle("tapped", forState: .Normal)
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2.0)
    button2.setTitle("tap me", forState: .Normal)
}

func isCancel(sender:UIAlertAction!){
}

@IBAction func button2Tapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Test", message: "button", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: isOK))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: isCancel))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

OK,
i changed to this:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var button1: UIButton!
@IBAction func button1Tapped(sender: UIButton) {
    sender.selected = true
    NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(2.0)
    sender.selected = false
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    button1.setTitle("tapped", forState: .Selected)
    button1.setTitle("tap me", forState: .Normal)
}
```

but it shows the same behaviour.
Actually it shows "tapped" but only when i keep pressing!?

Comment: So you want to tap a button, and then after two seconds you want to change the title of the button?

Comment: Yes!
I have to investigate your answer, Thank you so far!

Comment: My pleasure. Hope my answer works well for you.

Comment: no sorry! didn't help, same behaviour!

Comment: @IanMcDonald: will look for your solution!
Seems complicated for a simple button!? ;-)

Comment: Comment my answer saying what's working and what's not. Could you show me via a screenshot how exactly you use the code I gave you?

Comment: It's not complicated, I just wrote a lot of words. All you have to do is use `dispatch_after` instead of `NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval`... I literally wrote your `button1Tapped` implementation for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, delete all the code you have written. Instead, use this code that I have taken from answer of [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/1135714). Credits goes to him. This function is needed to "delay" the action of something.

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
dispatch_after(
    dispatch_time(
        DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
        Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
    ),
    dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

Now create an `@IBAction` connection:

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {
// Okay, the button has been tapped
  button.setTitle("tapped", forState: .Normal)

// after two seconds...
  delay(2.0) {

// change the button's title:
  button.setTitle("tap here!", forState: .Normal)

  }
}
```

Comment: i copied your code and used it as posted!
The title "tapped" does not show up!?
It only required me to add "self." to:             self.button1.setTitle("tap here!", forState: .Normal)

Comment: Try using both `.Selected` or both `.Normal` after `forState:`. Also are you getting any errors?

Comment: Aha! both .Normal works!
Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: Glad you got it working! In Swift we use `.Selected` if we want to change the image of the button. Especially in games if you press a button you see an push-over effect. Please check this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/KLjOP.png. In this case, `.Normal` is always needed because you aren't changing the image of the button.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems with the first way that you attempted is that you have simply set the title for two different states of `sender`: `.Highlighted` and `.Normal`. If you never change the state of `sender`, you'll only ever see the title associated with its current state (`.Normal` by default).

You could update the title for the same state twice to get the behaviour you want, or you might consider using the `.Selected` state of the button, depending on your application's implementation and usage of the button.

```
// Call these two setTitle lines wherever you are instantiating your button
// or otherwise setting up your view:
sender.setTitle("tapped", forState: .Selected)
sender.setTitle("tap me", forState: .Normal)

// Somewhere else, you can call either of these:
sender.selected = YES // sender now shows "tapped"
sender.selected = NO  // sender now shows "tap me"
```

---

Secondly, we need to address your threading issues.

At some point, the main thread has been scheduled to run the code contained within your `isOK` method. It also has work scheduled to update the UI. Your main thread's queue might look something like this:

```
(0): __ execute isOK(..)
(1): __ do some other stuff
(2): __ update the UI
(3): __ do some other stuff
```

If you update your UI in `(0)` and then update it again in `(0)`, the first update won't be seen because the queue hasn't been allowed to progress to `(2)` in between. When you `NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval()` in `(0)`, you are delaying UI updates and freezing your app.

Instead, you'll want to put your sleep into a different queue and then inject your following commands back onto the main thread after your duration has elapsed.

You can do this in a few ways, but the easiest way is to use GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) and `dispatch_after`.

```
@IBAction func button1Tapped(sender: UIButton) {
  sender.selected = YES
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(2.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))),
                 dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    sender.selected = NO
  });
}
```

Comment: But isn't the code in isOK not scheduled only after the alert should have come up?
Why do i not see the alert?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you're asking. You've changed your implementation around quite a bit. In order to change your button text and then change it back 2 seconds later, you just need to set it, then call `dispatch_after` and unset it within the block you provide.

Comment: Sorry, but my examples are propably misleading. These are actually independent.
With the first snippet i wanted to test the settings of the button, independent of the second example with the alert.
Did you refer with your first code also to a threading problem!?
I tried your first code, but this didn't work!
My second example does not even show the alert!?

Comment: In your post, you have written some code after "OK, i changed to this:". This should be using the `button1Tapped` that I wrote at the end of my answer. Your `button2Tapped` is showing your alert possibly because you have defined the function twice and the first one is empty.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood your solution for example "button1". This works with your and CeCExx proposal. Thanks!
But what with my second example "button2"?
I can't see where i defined the function twice.

Comment: Sorry again! I just looked at my code more thoroughly. You are right, i declared the function twice. Stupid!